# Find the unique words in a list, count them up, while keep tracking of another variable

Tags: python

if given a txt file as the following, I need to output:
5 the movie was AMAZING!
4 best indie of the year.
3 the movie was okay.
1 worst acting ever seen
5 Oscar movie
2 reeks of rot work form start to finish
1 worst movie

enter a phrase to test: movie was amazing
*'movie' appears 4 times with an average score of 3.5
*'was' appears 2 times with an average score of 4.0
*'amazing' appears 1 time with an average score of 5.0
average score for this phrase is: 4.1666666666667
this is a positive phrase.

I've thus far been able to create a list of unique words but I kept trying different ways to configue the counter variable without success. I also am not sure how I can use index to keep track of the rating since I sliced them up to individual words. Is there a way to count up the unique words without turning all the reviews into one large list of words?

```
#remove punctuations and store the cleaned data
clean_data=''
punc = '''!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'''

split_data = data.split('\n')
#iterate over every character to check if it's punctuation
for character in data:
    if character not in punc:
       clean_data += character
    else:
        clean_data += ''


#store the cleaned reviews into a list of reviews
cleaned_str = clean_data.split('\n')


#seperate the ratings and reviews into two seperate lists
#they can be matched via index
score = []
reviews = []
for i in cleaned_str:
    score.append(int(i[0]))
    new_string = i[2:]
    reviews.append(new_string)




words = {}
unique = []
repeats = []
counter = 0 
#add all the words in all the reviews to one long string
#then turn into a list with all the words
reviews_words = ''
for i in reviews:
    reviews_words += str(i) + ' '
    word_list = reviews_words.split()

for word in word_list:
    if word not in unique:
        unique.append(word)
        counter +=1 
        repeats.append(counter)
    
    else:
        counter += 1
        repeats.append(counter)
```

I would appreciate any sort of hints! I'm not suppose to solve this with imported packages :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PUNCTUATION = r'''!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'''


def remove_punctuation(string):
    new_string = []
    for character in string:
        if character not in PUNCTUATION:
            new_string.append(character)

    return "".join(new_string)


scores = {}
counts = {}


with open('text.txt', 'r') as data:
    lines = data.readlines()


for line in lines:
    line = remove_punctuation(line)

    words = line.split()

    # Removes first 'word' from line which is the number rating
    score = int(words.pop(0))

    for word in words:
        if word in scores:
            scores[word] += score
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            scores[word] = score
            counts[word] = 1

for word in scores:
    scores[word] /= counts[word]
```

This gets you dictionaries with the scores and the count for the unique words (just print out scores and counts to have a look). Let me know if it works because I can't really test it since I don't have the text file you're using.